# Using \^{o} in text mode

Tags: errors

It might be silly, but I am not an expert:
When using ^{o} in text mode (I use Latex, \documentclass{book}), I receive the error message: "Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:çoi not set up for use with LaTeX."
The pdf looks good, still the error message is there at each compilation.
What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, sorry: It was my mistake, everything works. Sorry for loosing your time.

Comment: Why you are using `\^{o}` and not simply ô ?

Comment: @wipet: because I use an American keyboard.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is due to undisclosed issues which have been solved by the OP.